# Qmetry - How to update value of a key of api request in .wsc file

Tags: qaf

In Qmetry, I have placed api request data in requests.wsc file. For example in the below api request- want to update 'baseUrl' key value from 'https://google.com' to 'https://stackoverflow.com' through qmetry method/ or programmatically.

**api request content in requests.wsc file**:

```
get.sample.call={'headers':{'Accept':'application/xml'},'baseUrl':'https://google.com','method':'GET','query-parameters':{},'form-parameters':{},'body':''}
```

Can any one help me on achieving this within qmetry or any other way? Thanks!

Comment: Where and how you are using this request call? Can you provide that details? You can parameterize and provide values when you are actually using it.

Comment: Hi, In feature file , calling api as -  user requests 'get.sample.call' . Please let me know how can I update values through parametrization . any example will be very helpful!

Comment: @user861594, how to use this step -  user requests {request} with data {data}   . how to pass data here? any example will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer documentation of [Request Call Repository](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/wiki/Request-Call-Repository). You should use parameters and [parameter-resolution](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/wiki/Request-Call-Repository#parameter-resolution) done at the time of execution. For example:

```
get.sample.call={'headers':{'Accept':'application/xml'},'baseUrl':'${env.baseurl}','method':'GET','query-parameters':{},'form-parameters':{},'body':''}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!. I used step as -  user requests {'get.sample.call'} with data {'env.baseurl'= "https://stackoverflow.com"} .  I also want to update multiple values. For ex: want to update values of baseurl & method keys when calling api request. Can we send multiple paramters ? Please let me know with an example.

Comment: Yes you can have multiple parameters. Refre documentation for usage and examples